# Tab bar view doesn't find the correct selectedTab on swipe only

Tags: swiftui, tabs, tabview

I have a tab bar within a tab bar on one of my views and both seem to work well except when the child tab bar is swiped, then it returns the next two tabs instead of only the next tab, so nothing shows. I would like for you to be able to swipe into the child tab view, swipe through them, and then move on to the next parent tab. It works perfectly when you tap on the tab bar item though, just doesn't work on swipe.

**ProfileView (parent tab bar)**

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    @State private var currentTab = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Parent Tab Bar")
            TabView(selection: $currentTab) {
                Text("Tab 1")
                    .tag(0)
                ListView(viewModel: ListsViewModel())
                    .tag(1)
                Text("Tab 3")
                    .tag(2)
            }
                .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .clipped()
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
        }
    }
}
```

**ListsView, ListViewModel, and Lists enum**

```
enum Lists: String, CaseIterable {
    case current, nextUp, finished, shareable
}

class ListsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedList: Lists = .current
}

struct ListView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ListsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Child Tab Bar")
                .font(.title)
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 24) {
                    ForEach(Lists.allCases, id: \.self) { list in
                        Button(action: {
                            viewModel.selectedList = list
                        }) {
                            Text(list.rawValue.capitalized)
                                .font(.headline)
                                .foregroundColor(viewModel.selectedList == list ? .blue : .black)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            Divider()
                .padding(.top, 12)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            
            TabView(selection: $viewModel.selectedList) {
                ForEach(Lists.allCases, id: \.self) { list in
                    ScrollView {
                        VStack {
                            ForEach(0..<3) { index in
                                Text("\(list.rawValue) Tab Item \(index + 1)")
                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .tag(list)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .clipped()
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
        }
        .padding(.top, 12)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you swipe in the childTabView if there is no 
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never)) modifier there?

Comment: @lemonator21 thanks for calling that out. when i was making the MRE I removed that part on accident. should be accurate now

Comment: Okay I just tried out your code, I am able to swipe in to the child tabview, swipe between it's views and then out of it. What exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: Yes swiping works but the correct data isn't being pulled in when swiping, just on tap. When i print whats happening, on swipe it will return both "next" and "done" so I assume the code gets confused and doesn't return any data at all. My question is why it can't return the correct item on swipe but it does on tap @lemonator21

Comment: what data? 

This is printing the relevant case absolutely fine according to it's tab.

                            ForEach(0..<3) { index in
                                Text("\(list.rawValue) Tab Item \(index + 1)")
                                    .padding(.horizontal)
                            }

even when swiping